# How do you use WHERE BETWEEN clause in SQLite, when the values come from multiple tables?

Tags: sqlite, where-clause

I have the following tables (full schema included, however only the TIME values are necessary:

"POINTS" TABLE

```
     TSTAMP,                 LAT,   LON,     HDOP,    ALT,     FILE,        EUID
    "2015-12-15T20:29:54"   "0.0"   "0.0"   "99.99" "NULL"  "L151400.GPS"   "080D55"
    "2015-12-15T20:29:55"   "0.0"   "0.0"   "99.99" "NULL"  "L151400.GPS"   "080D55"
    "2015-12-15T20:29:56"   "0.0"   "0.0"   "99.99" "NULL"  "L151400.GPS"   "080D55"
```

"AUDIO" TABLE

```
START,                  STOP,                    NCHANNELS,     SAMPWIDTH,  FRAMERATE, NFRAMES, COMPTYPE, COMPNAME, FILE, FILESIZE, EUID
"2015-12-15T22:37:00"   "2015-12-15T22:39:53"   "1.0"   "2.0"   "16000.0"   "2777088.0" "NONE"  "not compressed"    "static/uploads/WAV/L151637.WAV"    "5554688.0"
"2015-12-15T22:27:00"   "2015-12-15T22:37:00"   "1.0"   "2.0"   "16000.0"   "9601024.0" "NONE"  "not compressed"    "static/uploads/WAV/L151627.WAV"    "19202560.0"
"2015-12-15T22:17:00"   "2015-12-15T22:27:00"   "1.0"   "2.0"   "16000.0"   "9601024.0" "NONE"  "not compressed"    "static/uploads/WAV/L151617.WAV"    "19202560.0"
```

I need to find each record in the POINTS table that has a TSTAMP which falls between any START / STOP pair of the AUDIO table.

Thus far I've tried iterations of the following:

```
SELECT FILE FROM POINTS 
WHERE (
TSTAMP
BETWEEN (SELECT START FROM AUDIO) AND 
(SELECT STOP FROM AUDIO)
);
```

Which returns 0. I know this data lines up, and given the right search statement I should have multiple records returned. However, I can't seem to find any references on how to address pulling columns from multiple tables in one search statement.

I know I could cluge this together in Python, but it seems like a normal job for SQL in general.

Still getting used to SQL, so please be explicit in your answers.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find each record in the POINTS table that has a TSTAMP which falls between any START / STOP pair of the AUDIO table. you can use following query. Also please dont use **start** as a column name this is a keyword in sqlite. i used **sta** you can change column name.

**select STA,STOP,
(select GROUP_CONCAT(POINTS.FILE) from POINTS where datetime(POINTS.TSTAMP) between  datetime(AUDIO.STA)  and datetime(AUDIO.STOP) ) as FIL
 from AUDIO 
 from AUDIO**

this will return comma separated list of data that will occur in range.Also i used following data to check

```
AUDIO
    STA                        STOP  
"2015-12-15T22:37:00"   "2015-12-15T22:39:53"
"2015-12-15T22:27:00"   "2015-12-15T22:37:00"
"2015-12-15T22:17:00"   "2015-12-15T22:27:00"

POINTS
     TSTAMP                 FILE 
"2015-12-15T22:29:54"   "L151400.GPS"
"2015-12-15T22:29:55"   "L151400.GPS"
"2015-12-15T22:29:56"   "L151400.GPS"

And following is the result
   STA                      STOP              FIL                       
"2015-12-15T22:37:00" "2015-12-15T22:39:53" "NULL"

"2015-12-15T22:27:00" "2015-12-15T22:37:00" "L151400.GPS,L151400.GPS,L151400.GPS"

"2015-12-15T22:17:00"   "2015-12-15T22:27:00"   "NULL"
```

Thanks

Comment: Ultimately a variation of your answer did the trick..thanks!
select START, STOP, (select GROUP_CONCAT(AUDIO.FILE) from POINTS where datetime(POINTS.TSTAMP) between datetime(AUDIO.START) and datetime(AUDIO.STOP) ) as FIL from AUDIO

Answer (score 1):

To match rows with possibly multiple matches, use a join:

```
SELECT Points.File
FROM Points
JOIN Audio ON Points.TStamp BETWEEN Audio.Start AND Audio.Stop;
```

This will return one row for each match. To remove duplicate files, use DISTINCT.

Comment: ambiguous column name: File: SELECT File FROM Points
JOIN Audio ON Points.TStamp BETWEEN Audio.Start AND Audio.Stop;

Comment: Specifying the table name makes it unambiguous.

Answer (score -1):

`Between` is suppose to be used with two values, as in:

```
BETWEEN A AND B
```

You're using sub queries to fill out `A` and `B`, which is fine, but those sub queries return more than 1 value and that's where your problem lie.

```
SELECT START FROM AUDIO
```

Will return:

```
"2015-12-15T22:37:00"
"2015-12-15T22:27:00"
"2015-12-15T22:17:00"
```

In this case, `Between` is trying to figure out "between these 3 dates and these other dates". Makes no sense. You need to make sure you're only getting 1 result back in your sub queries.

Asides from that, your usage of `TSTAMP BETWEEN A AND B` isn't wrong.

Comment: How would I define one value for each of the Clauses conditions?
Would something like (SELECT START FROM AUDIO AS AUDIO_START) do the trick? Or is there more going into that parenthesis set that what meets the eye?

Comment: The `AS` keyword isn't going to help with anything, that's just to label a result. If you want to run through the query with each paring of start and stop, you'll have to think of them as separate queries. I'm not sure if it's worth the time trying to create a huge loop in sql. Instead, I'd suggest in whatever you're running the SQL from, grab all rows of start/stop first and iterate through them, with each iteration plugging in those values to the query you actually want. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's what I'm working here as I monitor this thread. Glad I could get some validation on this. It's fairly straightforward in Python, just seems so wasteful given the speed of SQL. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, turns out I'm not much help. I'm not familiar with Python and the limitations of sqlite to know how to build the entire structure you're after.